# Jquery Last-Child or Nth-Child if == "SALE"

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a drop down menu and I am trying to change the last item of the list only if the string  equals "SALE" and make it RED. I am able to successfully select any item in the list by either using nth-child or last-child but not all drop downs have the `<li>` string `SALE`. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

```
jQuery('ul.top-cat-links li.top-cat-tops a:last-child').css('color','#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SALE` isn't directly in the `li` element, you can use `:has`:

```
ul.top-cat-links li.top-cat-tops:has(:contains("SALE")) a:last-child
```

If it is, you can just use `:contains`:

```
ul.top-cat-links li.top-cat-tops:contains("SALE") a:last-child
```

Using JavaScript to add classes like this isn't a good idea. Why don't you add them with your serverside language?

Comment: Thanks Blender. That worked but I had to remove the quotes in the sale string. Why isn't it a good idea to add via Javascript?

Comment: @Jgunzblazin: Why would you add it with JavaScript? It's easier to do it serverside.

Comment: I am fairly new at this. I am not sure how I would do it server-side.

Comment: @Jgunzblazin: How are you generating the HTML?

Comment: @ Blender. Is the only reason doing it server-side because it's easier?  Using your method above was pretty simple... I am using Demandware SASS Platform and creating html within .isml templates.

Comment: @Jgunzblazin: It's simple, but it's not very clean nor is it a good way to do it. Users with JavaScript disabled (there are many) won't be able to use your site properly.